# MySQL Aggregate Column Different Conditions Query Never Ends

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large MySQL table consisting of three columns structured like the below

```
DATETIME          | UNITID | VALUE
----------------------------------
 2017-01-01 00:00 | A      | 50
 2017-01-01 00:00 | B      | 54
 2017-01-01 00:00 | C      | 12
 2017-01-01 00:05 | A      | 9
 2017-01-01 00:05 | B      | 8
 2017-01-01 00:05 | C      | 55
 2017-01-01 00:10 | A      | 12
```

With `DATETIME` and `UNITID` as the INDEX.

The total length of the table is 33 million rows comprising ~4 years of data and ~300 unit IDs

What I am looking to do is aggregate this by groups of `UNITID` e.g.

```
DATETIME          | VALUE(AB) | VALUE(C)
----------------------------------------
 2017-01-01 00:00 | 104       | 12
 2017-01-01 00:05 | 17        | 55
 2017-01-01 00:10 | 12        | Null
```

I have been able to create a query to do this as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.DATETIME AS DATETIME,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(VALUE)
        FROM
            tbl_name AS T2
        WHERE
            T2.DATETIME= T1.DATETIME
                AND T2.UNITID IN ('A', 'B')) AS VALUE(AB),
    (SELECT 
            SUM(VALUE)
        FROM
            tbl_name AS T3
        WHERE
            T3.DATETIME= T1.DATETIME
                AND T3.UNITID IN ('C')) AS VALUE(C)
FROM
    tbl_name AS T1
WHERE
    DATETIME >= '2017-01-01'
        AND DATETIME <= '2017-01-02 23:55'
```

I actually have around 10 Groups of UNITID's that I pass to the query and it successfully works if I include a `LIMIT` on the query e.g. limiting to 100000 rows takes 12 seconds to fetch but taking off the limit it just never ends. My SQL skills aren't great and I can't work out what is causing this. Note that for this query there are only ~105000 distinct rows

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT  DATETIME,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UNITID IN ('A', 'B') THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS AB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UNITID = 'C' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM tbl_name
WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN '2017-01-01'AND '2017-01-02 23:55'
GROUP BY DATETIME
```

There is no need to use correlated subqueries. You can get the same result using *conditional aggregation*.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/VULA65812)